# Best season for Norway fjords cruise?

Tags: cruising, norway, fjords

My spouse and I are planning a trip, probably with the Hurtigruten ferry/cruise line), and thinking about when to go.

We'd like a good chance of seeing the aurora, but also enough light hours to see landscapes and towns. It seems like late March or very early April could be a good compromise time. Does that make sense?

We're also thinking this season would offer us the benefit of seeing different kinds of landscapes - snow-covered up north, and not further south. Does that seem right?

Comment: If you go a bit later (say mid to late May) you should be able to see the landscape in the far north starting back into growth and then track that as you go south.

Comment: I have been to Bergen in South Western Norway in April and had snow, it just depends on what the weather is like that year. Later on in late May the Fjords have spectacular water falls coming down their sides as the snow cap melts.

Answer (score 1):

We were in Svolvaer (Lofoten Isl) in May this year and took a day trip out  to fish an see White Tail Eagles. We met up with a Hurtigruten cruise ship after fishing and took on board 40 of its passengers before venturing into the fjord to see the eagles swooping down to feed. i.e., fish was thrown overboard to encourage them down. Cold yes, but we were well wrapped up and still walked plenty. It snowed lightly each day but not enough to lie around and inhibit sight seeing although plenty of snow high up. Fantastic time of the year because you see everything and get an appreciation of what it would be like mid-winter.